# Excel VBA Shell FTP Logging

Tags: vba, shell, excel, ftp

So I have code that creates a sequence of steps in a text file in the temp directory and then executes the shell FTP.  The question I have is, once the shell is launched and is running through the FTP, is it possible to log the FTP results?  Like if a file failed to upload or *"can't find file name"* etc? This way I can be away from the computer while the script is pushing files to the FTP and later look at the log to see what failed and why.

This is my FTP launch command:

```vb
Sub executeFTPBatch(ByVal ftpfileName)
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wsh.Run "FTP -i -s:C:\Temp\" & ftpfileName & ".txt", 1, True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try monitoring to output of the Run command: `result = wsh.Run(...` then `If result<>0 Then MsgBox "Error: " & result`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect the output of the `ftp.exe` to a file:

```vb
wsh.Run "%comspec% /c FTP  -i -s:C:\Temp\" & ftpfileName & ".txt > c:\path\ftp.log 2>&1", 1, True
```

See also https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for teaching me this!